# ELF read/write in other process memory

Tags: elf

Is there an equivalent of ReadProcessMemory windows function for reading (or writing) in another process memory ?
I have tried to preload a shared library, i have also tried to debug (ptrace, peek and poke memory). It seems to work, but i am wondering if there is not a simplest way...

Comment: What does this have to do with ELF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent of ReadProcessMemory

Yes: [man ptrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html) (`PTRACE_PEEKDATA`, etc.)

The `ptrace` interface is generic to UNIX, and has nothing to do with `ELF` (i.e. it also works on systems that use `COFF`, or `AOUT` as their normal executable format).

> Is this this simplest way?

It's the *only* way on most UNIX platforms.

On Linux, you could also read/write `/proc/$pid/mem`. Note however, that many kernels disable this for security reasons (having this file read/writable presents a *huge* security attack surface).

On Solaris, there has been a different `/proc` [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5174/6mbb98ui2/index.html), but (as far as I can tell) it has not been adopted on any other system.

Comment: Quoting OP: "*i have also tried to debug (ptrace, ...  i am wondering if there is not a simplest way*"

Comment: Yes i have tried this. But is there a simplest way ?